# Geometry question considering triangles and cyclic quads

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and $P$ a point on the circumcircle of this triangle. Let $U$, $V$, and $W$ be the projections of $P$ onto the three sides of the triangle. Show that the points $U$, $V$, and $W$ are collinear. The line determined by them is called the *Simson line*. Hint. See Figure 1.

[image]

Your ﬁnal goal is to show that $\angle BVU \cong \angle CVW$  (this implies automatically that $U$, $V$, $W$ are collinear). First show that the quadrilaterals 
$\square BVPU$ and $\square CWVP$ are cyclic (use question 4, HW 4). Deduce that $\angle BVU \cong ∠BPU$ and $\angle CVW \cong \angle CPW$ (justify these!). The fact that $\angle BPU \cong \angle CPW$ follows from $\angle UPW \cong \angle BPC$. In turn, this follows from the fact that the quadrilaterals $\square AUPW$ and $\square ABPC$ are cyclic.

I am having a hard time proving that $\square CWVP$ is a cyclic quad. Can you give any hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$BVPU$ and $CWVP$ have two right angles, therefore they are cyclic.

(i.e. $CWVP$ is inscribed in a circle with diameter $WP$)

If you are having troubles with such things first read [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral) on cyclic quadrilaterals

Comment: BVPU and CWVP have two right angles, therefore they are cyclic, is a bit confusing. You should have explained that sum of two opposite have to be 180 degrees, and so it cyclic.